# Converting geodatabase public lands to a shapefile

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, file-geodatabase

Can a whole geodatabase be converted to a single shapefile? This is my code, not sure what I am doing wrong...

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy

# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/UW/Winter_2016/501/pythonProject/publicLandsData/pLDWorkspace"

nfc = "publicLandsDataToGDB"
fp = "D:/UW/Winter_2016/501/pythonProject/publicLandsData/pLDWorkspace/publicLandsDataConversion.gdb"

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(fp, nfc, "Polygon","","","", "WGS 1984")
arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion("D:/UW/Winter_2016/501/pythonProject/publicLandsData/waParksGDB/WA_PublicLandsInventory_2014_r1.3_UWSEFS_PublicInfo.gdb",
                                         "D:/UW/Winter_2016/501/pythonProject/publicLandsData/newShapefiles")
```

the error is saying Execute Error which I believe is an arcpy function, that the input features: Dataset: "variouspathname.gdb" does not exist or is not supported..

Comment: No, you usually cannot convert multiple feature classes in a geodatabase into a single shapefile.  The only exception being when all the feature classes have the same exact table structure and topology class (which would then require an Append operation).  In essence, you're trying to convert a directory to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to generate a list using `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses` and iterate over the list, exporting each feature class out to a shapefile. The [documentation for ListFeatureClasses](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/listfeatureclasses.htm) has an example of the reverse, copying shapefiles to a file geodatabase.